# How can I batch add keywords (metadata) to JPGs, with matching?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, keywords

I have a weird situation in on my hands and hope to find some direction/hints...

The ultimate goal is to have a Lightroom catalog with about 30 000 keyworded images in it.

The images are all JPEG, inside a single folder, each with unique numerical name, like 123456789.jpg.

The keywords are inside a mysql database and I can dump them and/or process the list in whatever format needed (for example tab/space separated "filename"-"keywords" value).

I know I can import keywords from text files in LR, but that won't match them to the images, AFAIK. So I presume I have to first run some kind of EXIF batch to match filename to keyword set and insert the keywords in JPEG files. After that I hope LR will recognize the EXIF during import (I've tested that and it seems to work).

So that's about it. Any help appreciated!

PS: The two topics I found helpful in the final resolution of the problem:

- MYSQL to CSV: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-mysqldump-to-save-data-to-csv-files/
- EXIFTOOL and CSV: https://ExifTool.org/forum/index.php/topic,3544.msg16107.html#msg16107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could export the tags as a batch script that runs [exiftool](https://ExifTool.org/) to add the keywords to the JPEG files:

```
exiftool -keywords+=banana 111.jpg
exiftool -keywords+=fruit 111.jpg
exiftool -keywords+=tree 112.jpg
...
```

with a query resembling this:

```
select concat('exiftool -keywords+=',KEYWORD,' ',FILE_NUMBER,'.jpg') from IMAGE
```

and then

- backup your images
- run the generated batch script
- import the images into Lightroom

Comment: Thanks for the exiftool pointer! Extremely useful tool, as it seems! What I did was similar:
- mysqldump -T with --fields-terminated-by=,
- exiftool -csv="name of csv file" *.jpg
- import into LR

The test with 10 images was successful, now it's time to run the whole 30 000 :)